# Customize Hyperlink hover-over

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Excel generates some instruction text when you hover-over a hyperlink as such...

[image]

Can I customize these instructions and set my own text (the "Click once to follow.  Click and hold...")

Comment: Do you need a solution that works in all versions of Excel? If so, please remove the version-specific Excel tags as the generic `microsoft-excel` tag indicates you want a version agnostic solution.

Comment: I do need a solution that works in all modern versions (2007+).  Removed the version-specific tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can say there are two situations.

- Create Hyperlink by using the standard Excel Command **Insert**, **Hyperlink**.
- Use the built-in **Hyperlink Function**.

*When you use the **Insert Hyperlink** command all the parameters are available.*

- Address
- Text to Display
- Screen Tips

While using the command you have the liberty to customize the Hyperlink. During hover the link, the text which appears is in fact the **Screen Tip** which can be any text of user's choice.

Other is **Text to Display**, this replaces the Web Address and appears on the Sheet.

**Other Advantage is**, the Hyperlink can be modified in terms of Font, Size & Colour while select the Hyperlink and Right Click and hit Format Cell (Ver. 2010 or higher) or in older Versions Modify command can do all these.

**But when you use the built-in Hyperlink function**, you can't add the Screen Tip. Here Formatting Hyperlink is available but user can't enjoy the Edit Hyperlink command sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the HYPERLINK function in the help.

```
=HYPERLINK("www.google.com", "Link to google")
```

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, I updated my post to clarify.  I want to modify the "Click once to follow. Click and hold..."

Comment: That's a bit more of a challenge.  https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/491587-disable-hyperlink-hover-info.html has some craziness with creating a dll from within the excel workbook.  I don't recommend that ;-)